# mysqli_connect not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on localhost:81 to check my php files. Meanwhile, I'm trying to connect to a mysql db that I created on phpmyadmin.However, it's not connecting. Is there anything to modify due to localhost:81?

```
<?php
     $con= mysqli_connect("shareddb-w.hosting.stackcp.net","users_db-313439571a","xxxxxxx");

     if($con){
         echo "NO ERROR";
     }
     else{
         echo "ERROR";
     }
?>
```

Comment: are you running your code on your local machine ( and unable to connect ) or on the PHP server ( webhost ) ?

Comment: I installed MAMP which started a server at port 81. So I'm running it on the server if that's what you're asking. @RamRaider

Comment: I'd guess that the live DB is protected by a firewall. From the live webhost he connection might be possible but many hosts prevent direct access to databases like this... you might want to speak to your provider

Comment: @RamRaider I'm following the steps of a UDEMY course. They actually did the same and they were able to connect.

Comment: Can it be because I'm not using Port 80?

Comment: it is unlikely. The mysql server and the webserver operate independently and their usual ports are not in the same region at all. Can you connect using a simple script from your web host?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_connect_error()` to check the error.
[See PHP manual for details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)